# Evaluating $\int x\sin^{-1}x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I was integrating $$\int x\sin^{-1}x dx.$$
After applying integration by parts and some rearrangement  I  got stuck at $$\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx.$$
Now I have two questions:

> 1. Please, suggest any further approach from where I have stuck;
> 2. Please, provide an alternative way to solve the original question.

Please help!!!

Comment: Using one of the magic words of integration: "Let $x=\sin u$..."

Comment: If I am not mistaking, wouldn't it will become $\cos u~d\sin u$ ? How will I integrate it with respect to $\sin u$?? @ J.M.isn'tamathematician

Comment: How do you differentiate the sine?

Comment: Oops I got it ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\cos{t}$, where $t\in[0,\pi]$.

Hence, $\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=-\sin^{2}tdt=-\frac{1-\cos2t}{2}dt$

Comment: Also works, but you now have a dangling minus sign to carry around.

Comment: @J. M. isn't a mathematician I think to say $x=\sin{t}$ without $t\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ it's very bad.

Comment: Well, since this isn't definite integration, we can be slightly sloppy here...

Comment: @J. M. isn't a mathematician Without previous condition we must write $\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos{x}|$.

Answer (score 2):

By parts,

$$I:=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$

But $x^2=1-(1-x^2)$ and you get
$$I:=x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\arcsin x-I.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative way:** Let $x=\sin t$ so 
$$\int x\sin^{-1}x dx=\int t\sin t\cos t dt$$
by parts $t=u$ and $\sin t\cos t dt=dv$ and finish it!

Comment: A further simplification would be using $\sin t\cos t=\frac{\sin 2t}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll proceed from the point you got stuck,

$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$

First, let $x = \sin y$, and thus $dx = \cos y\,dx$. Now substituting in the above integral,

$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2} = \int \sqrt{1-\sin^2 y} \, \cos y \, dy  $$
$$= \int \sqrt{\cos^2 y}  \, \cos y \, dy   = \int \cos y \, \cdot \cos y\, dy  $$

$$ = \int \cos^2 y \, dy $$

Now using Pythagorean Identity we can write, 
$$ \cos^2 y = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos 2y}{2} $$

Finally the integration becomes,

$$\int \frac{1}{2} dy + \int \frac{\cos 2y}{2}dy  $$

Go ahead now. Remember, $y = \sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: I think $\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos{x}|$. See please,  my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes absolutely but as it's an indefinite integral we can get irresponsible a bit.

Comment: I understand you, but I don'd like this thing.